# Can anyone suggest a reference to learn about relative log-likelihood and likelihood intervals?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, self-learning

I want to understand how to calculate the 10% likelihood interval for a Poisson model of count data. It is an old assignment where they give you 20 counts, tell you it is a Poisson model and ask you to derive the log-likelihood function (which I think I have done correctly), plot it, calculate the information of the MLE (again I think I have done this correctly) and then calculate the likelihood interval. The last step has me beat. From where I am it seems it cannot be done without using a numerical approximation but I have no reference to check my understanding of the steps that got me to this point.